# Slick: Quit game via button

Tags: java, slick2d

What methods can I use to tell the game that the user has requested it to close with either the `GameContainer` or the `StateBasedGame` classes.

I have a button and upon it being clicked I want it to close the game, what is the function that needs to be run upon the listener finding out that close was requested?

Comment: I apologise for the stupid question.  I was unsure if I needed to run any shutdown scripts at the time.  I will implement so that it is saved upon entering the QuitGameState.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GameContainer` class has an `exit` method:

```
public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame game, int delta) throws SlickException
{
  if(my_exit_flag)
    gc.exit();

  // Update code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can close **any java application** using

```
System.exit();
```

or

```
System.exit(<error_level>);
```